# How to add test-scoped artifacts of sbt project to another's test classpath?

Tags: sbt

There are two sbt projects: `common` and `projectX`.

The project `common` has some dependencies in the `test` scope that I want to see on the `test` classpath in the `projectX` which has `common` as dependency.

This is the excerpt from `build.sbt` in `projectX` with `test->test` configuration mapping as described in [Configurations](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/docs/Library-Management.html#ivy-configurations):

```
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "org" %% "common" % "0.1" % "compile->compile;test->test"
)
```

Upon executing `test:compile` in `projectX` the following error shows up:

> [error] (*:update) sbt.ResolveException: unresolved dependency:
>   org#common_2.10;0.1: configuration not public in org#common_2.10;0.1:
>   'test'. It was required from org#projectX_2.10;0.0.1-SNAPSHOT test

How to add the `test`-scoped dependencies in project `common` to the `test` classpath in the project `projectX`?

Answer (score 4):

I've never seen the error before and can't reproduce it, but it looks like the test artifacts have not been `publishLocal`ed as they are not by default.

According to [Selecting default artifacts](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13.5/docs/Detailed-Topics/Artifacts.html):

> By default, the published artifacts are the main binary jar, a jar
>   containing the main sources and resources, and a jar containing the
>   API documentation. You can add artifacts for the test classes,
>   sources, or API or you can disable some of the main artifacts.
>
> To add all test artifacts:
>
> ```
> publishArtifact in Test := true
> ```

And that's what you're supposed to do to publish the artifcts for the `test` configuration.

Add the following to `build.sbt` of the `common` project and `publishLocal` it to have the tests packaged and published to the local Ivy2 repository:

```
publishArtifact in Test := true
```

With the change you should see the following in the logs of `publishLocal` - mind the test-related artifacts:

```
> common/publishLocal
[info] Packaging /Users/jacek/sandbox/multi-module-test-scope-25003683/common/target/scala-2.10/common_2.10-0.1-sources.jar ...
[info] Packaging /Users/jacek/sandbox/multi-module-test-scope-25003683/common/target/scala-2.10/common_2.10-0.1-tests-sources.jar ...
[info] Done packaging.
[info] Done packaging.
[info] Updating {file:/Users/jacek/sandbox/multi-module-test-scope-25003683/}common...
[info] Wrote /Users/jacek/sandbox/multi-module-test-scope-25003683/common/target/scala-2.10/common_2.10-0.1.pom
[info] Resolving org.fusesource.jansi#jansi;1.4 ...
[info] Done updating.
[info] :: delivering :: org#common_2.10;0.1 :: 0.1 :: release :: Mon Jul 28 23:00:41 CEST 2014
[info]  delivering ivy file to /Users/jacek/sandbox/multi-module-test-scope-25003683/common/target/scala-2.10/ivy-0.1.xml
[info] Packaging /Users/jacek/sandbox/multi-module-test-scope-25003683/common/target/scala-2.10/common_2.10-0.1-javadoc.jar ...
[info] Done packaging.
[info] Packaging /Users/jacek/sandbox/multi-module-test-scope-25003683/common/target/scala-2.10/common_2.10-0.1.jar ...
[info] Done packaging.
[info] Test Scala API documentation to /Users/jacek/sandbox/multi-module-test-scope-25003683/common/target/scala-2.10/test-api...
[info] Compiling 1 Scala source to /Users/jacek/sandbox/multi-module-test-scope-25003683/common/target/scala-2.10/test-classes...
model contains 2 documentable templates
[info] Test Scala API documentation successful.
[info] Packaging /Users/jacek/sandbox/multi-module-test-scope-25003683/common/target/scala-2.10/common_2.10-0.1-tests-javadoc.jar ...
[info] Done packaging.
[info] Packaging /Users/jacek/sandbox/multi-module-test-scope-25003683/common/target/scala-2.10/common_2.10-0.1-tests.jar ...
[info] Done packaging.
[info]  published common_2.10 to /Users/jacek/.ivy2/local/org/common_2.10/0.1/docs/common_2.10-javadoc.jar
[info]  published common_2.10 to /Users/jacek/.ivy2/local/org/common_2.10/0.1/srcs/common_2.10-tests-sources.jar
[info]  published common_2.10 to /Users/jacek/.ivy2/local/org/common_2.10/0.1/jars/common_2.10-tests.jar
[info]  published common_2.10 to /Users/jacek/.ivy2/local/org/common_2.10/0.1/jars/common_2.10.jar
[info]  published common_2.10 to /Users/jacek/.ivy2/local/org/common_2.10/0.1/srcs/common_2.10-sources.jar
[info]  published common_2.10 to /Users/jacek/.ivy2/local/org/common_2.10/0.1/poms/common_2.10.pom
[info]  published common_2.10 to /Users/jacek/.ivy2/local/org/common_2.10/0.1/docs/common_2.10-tests-javadoc.jar
[info]  published ivy to /Users/jacek/.ivy2/local/org/common_2.10/0.1/ivys/ivy.xml
[success] Total time: 2 s, completed Jul 28, 2014 11:00:43 PM
```

Comment: Unfortunately I had this option set already `publishArtifact in Test := true` but it does not change anything. Also note that I don't need test classes of `common` - I just need the classpath to have its dependencies. Artifact is also published for sure.

Comment: Looking at your log I get the feeling that you reproduced it in a multi-module setting. There are no modules. These are 2 standalone, seperate projects, where `projectX` has dependency on `common`.

Comment: The name `multi-module-test-scope-25003683` is misleading as I had started with a multi-module project with `dependsOn` and then realized you used the dependency in a different way. The two projects share the directory, but they depend on each other via the local Ivy2 repository.

Comment: As to the test classpath...you can't depend on CLASSPATH but artifacts. So to establish a dependency between projects you have to depend on their artifacts. Since `projectX` depends on the test artifact, that in turn depends on other artifacts, they all constitute the test CLASSPATH.

Answer (score 0):

I have had success in solving this problem *without* publishLocal by switching from Maven-style to Ivy-style publishing and resolving (Ivy files instead of pom files, and Ivy-style repositories). By the way, if you use a Nexus proxy, it is recommended to keep Maven repos and Ivy repos (and likewise Maven groups and Ivy groups) completely separate in Nexus.

That said, I don't know why you have this problem *with* publishLocal - that should definitely work if you have the `publishArtifact` line in your *source* project build file correctly.